# Configure VSCode to show squiggles for specific level

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode it is possible to filter warnings and errors by level via "Show Errors", "Show Warnings", "Show Infos" checkboxes. But those only affect the "Problems" panel.

Is there a way to similarly filter the squiggles that underline the source code that causes those warnings?

For example, I would like to see errors (= red squiggles) but not warnings or info-level hints (yellow and blue squiggles).

Ideally this would be a workspace-level configuration.

I expect this to be a language-agnostic feature, but I'm using Python with Pylint through Microsoft's extension.

Comment: you can make the colors for these squiggles transparent

Comment: Haha, that technically works! Is this common or suggested by the vscode team?

Comment: Unfortunately extensions like ErrorLens that rely on this information have to be configured separately.